# How can i update a edited value from a textarea?

Tags: php

i'm building my project in PHP and i have a page to edit some values from a specific row.

So, to edit those values, i inserted them inside a textbox to edit and send the final value.

The problem is that i'm sending this value doing that:

```
<td><input class='txtedit' type='text' name='u_localization[".$val['id']."]' value='".$val['localization']."' /></td>
```

I'm getting the value from the textbox and is working.

But i dont know how to send the value from textareas, because i have to do that to show the row text.

```
<textarea name"namehere"> Value must be here </textarea>
```

And i can't get the value from the textarea because i'm not using that:

```
name="value"
```

How can i update values using a textarea?

Comment: Did you get an answer? Accept one?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about textareas. They're basically  just `<input type="text">` that happen to allow multi-line inputs.

```
<textarea name="foo">some random text</textarea>
                ^^^--- this name

echo $_POST['foo']; // outputs "some random text"
```

Comment: You don't. That's why there's textboxes and textareas

Answer (score 0):

By "textbox" do you mean input-text element or textarea element?
input-text elements are self closing; you can have an initial value with "value=".
textareas don't have the "value" attribute.
Both elements have the "name" attribute, which become the $_POST keys.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="formnm" action="forms/form0.php" method="post">
Form:
<fieldset>
<legend>fieldset</legend>
InputText: <input type="text" name="textnm" value="initial value" /><br />
Textarea:  <textarea name="textareanm" rows="2" cols="50">
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Button" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the contents of the text area and echo it out as required.

Sample form:

```
 <?php

$textAreaContents =<<<'EOD'
Twinkle, twinkle, little star
How I wonder what you are.

Twinkle, twinkle, little star
How I wonder what you are.
Up above the world so high
Like a diamond in the sky
EOD;

if (!empty($_POST['textarea1'])) {
    $textAreaContents = $_POST['textarea1'];
}

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
            <legend>Test of Text Area</legend>
            <textarea name="textarea1" rows="12" cols="75"><?php echo $textAreaContents; ?></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <legend>Go for it...</legend>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit Your edits" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```